# Get the content of a textblock in a combobox.itemtemplate

Tags: c#, itemtemplate

I've managed to put different String Date into a ComboBox using TextBlock items with Data Binding, and then I'd like to get the text of the selected item in my ComboBox,here is my WPF code :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListProgram, ElementName=Window}" x:Name="date">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="test" Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I tried this but it displayed nothing :

```
Console.WriteLine(date.Text);
```

I also tried this and it's still not working :

```
Console.WriteLine(test.Text);
```

Thanks a lot, a French beginner programmer.

Comment: You can get the string by calling ToString() on the Date property of your view model. That is was the text box actually does.

Comment: I tried `Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());` but it displays : "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox"

Comment: @qlthd because `date` **is** a ComboBox. First line of your code: `<ComboBox x:Name="date">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is a `ComboBox` so it's only natural for `date.ToString()` to return `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox`.

You want to get **the value of the selected item of date** which is not the control itself.

First, you can omit the `DataTemplate`. `strings` get turned into `TextBoxes` automatically. Just specify the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` (`"Date"` in your case, but you can choose different properties of course) and WPF will take care of the rest.

- `DisplayMemberPath` tells the ComboBox which property of the item to use to *display* the item.
- `SelectedValuePath` tells the ComboBox which property to use for `SelectedValue`

```xaml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListProgram, ElementName=Window}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Date" SelectedValuePath="Date" x:Name="date">
</ComboBox>
```

In your code you can get the selected item (or it's value) with:

```cs
date.SelectedValue // will return the "Date" property of the selected Item
date.SelectedItem  // will return the item itself
date.Text          // will return the string it is displaying
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear explanation, i got it now !